# What is the intuition behind flipping filters during convolution?

Tags: filter, conv-neural-network, theano, convolution

I saw that, while using the conv2d function of Theano, the filters were flipped both vertically and horizontally. Why is that? And does it matter in the case of a Convolutional Neural Network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is how [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is defined mathematically. Without the flipping of filter, the operation is called [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation). The advantage of convolution is that it has nicer mathematical properties.

However in the context of Convolutional Neural Network it doesn't matter whether you use convolution or cross-correlation, they are equivalent. This is because the weights of filters are learned during the training, i.e. they are updated to minimize a cost function. In a CNN that uses the cross-correlation operation, the learned filters will be equal to the flipped learned filters of a CNN that uses the convolution operation (assuming exactly the same training conditions for both, i.e. same initialization, inputs, number of epochs etc.). So the outputs of such two CNNs will be the same for the same inputs.

Cross-correlation operation is slightly more intuitive and simpler to implement (because no flipping is performed) and that's probably the reason why other frameworks like Tensorflow and Pytorch use it instead of the actual convolution (they still call it convolution though, probably due to historical reasons or to be consistent in terminology with other frameworks that use the actual convolution).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add in to the above post, even though we say we are using "convolution" operation in CNNs, we actually use cross correlation. But both convolution and correlation produces different outcomes, and I did this exercise to actually see the difference in outcomes.

When I reserached more on this topic, I found that the very initial inception of CNNs is considered to be originated from the paper Neocognitron, which is known to use convolutional operation while using the kernel operation, but later implementations of CNNs and most Deep Learning libraries are known to use correlation filtering instead of convolutional filtering, and we still kept using the name of Convolutional Neural Networks as mostly the algorithm complexities and performance remained almost same.

If you want a detailed article and intuition on how both differ, please take a look at this: https://towardsdatascience.com/does-cnn-represent-convolutional-neural-networks-or-correlational-neural-networks-76c1625c14bd

Let me know if this helps. :)

Comment: I liked your effort to show the difference between convolution and correlation with a Gaussian Blur filter. But I have two questions.

1. I think a Gaussian Blur filter would be symmetrical. Then how come the flipping causes any change at all?

2. And if the filter is not symmetrical, what will happen if the network learned the flipped version of a Gaussian Blur filter? Then doing a convolution operation will result in a nice blurred image and a correlation operation will produce that grainy image. Right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: To answer your questions:
1. The filters does not necessarily be have to be symmetrical. Let's your actual filter is [[1,2],[3,4]] and image region where the filter is being applied is [[1,-1], [-1,-1]], the output of correlation would be -8, but if you flip both sides and essentially do convolution the resultant sum of products will be -2 , so essentially the outputs are not same.
2. The main point in CNN is not to learn the weights to produce a blurry image, but rather to learn weights to get meaningful features, which in most cases done better with correlation than actual convolution

Comment: May be try this out yourself :) and see if you get any difference in a full CNN operation. I did this exercise, and my model with correlation had an accuracy boost by 15% but the one with actual convolution was 15% less accurate on same training data and same model architecture.